# Database capacity on hpanel Hostinger keeps increasing

Tags: database, woocommerce

I use Hostinger's shared hosting, am having the problem that the database capacity in hpanel automatically increases continuously, while the database capacity in phpmyadmin. While not performing any operations or updates on the website.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xx8Y.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMGMj.png)

I have tried disabling all plugins and switching back to the default wordpress theme but the data size keeps increasing.